# Compare performance of Concurrent Dictionary with Dictionary+Locks

Tags: c#, .net, performance, dictionary

I wanted to measure the performance of Concurrent Dictionary vs Dictionary+Locks in a multithreaded environment. So I created my own SyncDict class of type`<int,int[]>`. Whenever there is a key match, it adds the `int[]` array value to itself, it also locks the whole dictionary with ReaderWriterLockSlim while updating the value.

I replicated the code through Concurrent Dictionary and I am mainly using `AddOrUpdate()` method.
 
Whole console app code can be found here https://dotnetfiddle.net/1kFbGy Just copy paste the code in console app to run. It will not run fiddle

After running both codes with the same inputs I see a considerable amount of difference in running time. For example for one particular run on my machine Concurrent dictionary took 4.5 seconds vs SyncDict took less than 1 second.

I would like to know any thoughts / suggestions explaining the above running time. Is there anything wrong am I doing here.

```
 class SyncDict<TKey>
    {
        private ReaderWriterLockSlim cacheLock;
        private Dictionary<TKey, int[]> dictionary;
        public SyncDict()
        {
            cacheLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
            dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, int[]>();
        }

        public Dictionary<TKey, int[]> Dictionary
        {
            get { return dictionary; }
        }

        public int[] Read(TKey key)
        {
            cacheLock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                return dictionary[key];
            }
            finally
            {
                cacheLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }

        public void Add(TKey key, int[] value)
        {
            cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                dictionary.Add(key, value);
            }
            finally
            {
                cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }

        public AddOrUpdateStatus AddOrUpdate(TKey key, int[] value)
        {
            cacheLock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
            try
            {
                int[] result = null;
                if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out result))
                {
                    if (result == value)
                        return AddOrUpdateStatus.Unchanged;
                    else
                    {
                        cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
                        try
                        {
                            Parallel.For(0, value.Length,
                            (i, state) =>
                            {
                                result[i] = result[i] + value[i];
                            });
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
                        }
                        return AddOrUpdateStatus.Updated;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Add(key, value);
                    return AddOrUpdateStatus.Added;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                cacheLock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
            }
        }

        public void Delete(TKey key)
        {
            cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                dictionary.Remove(key);
            }
            finally
            {
                cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }

        public enum AddOrUpdateStatus
        {
            Added,
            Updated,
            Unchanged
        };
    }
```

Comment: You're using the newer Slim locks. They are faster if the period of the lock isn't long, but consume more CPU resource and can be slower for longer locks. That would be my first guess.

Comment: Can somebody explain the vote down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems with [your test](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1kFbGy).

1) You are populating a dictionary with ~150.000 different keys, all with the same value.

2) The shared value of all entries is an array of 30.000 integers, and you are updating every element of it at half of the calls to `AddOrUpdate`. But this only happens when you test the `ConcurrentDictionary`. At the `SyncDict` test there is a condition `if (result == value) return AddOrUpdateStatus.Unchanged` that skips all updates (because the value is shared).

3) You are feeding the two tests with different random inputs.

4) You are updating the array using a `Parallel.For` loop, while already being in an outer `Parallel.For` loop, over-parallelizing your workload.

5) <del>When calling the method `AddOrUpdate` you ignore the documented fact that the `updateValueFactory` function is called in a thread-unsafe manner, and since multiple `AddOrUpdate` are executed synchronously and the value is shared, you are corrupting the state of the value.</del>

> The `updateValueFactory` delegate is called outside the locks to avoid the problems that can arise from executing unknown code under a lock.
>   [**ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate Method**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate)

I suggest that you modify your test to reflect the intended use of the `ConcurrentDictionary` class.

Comment: Oops! I missed that you are returning a new array from the `UpdateArray` function. The point 5 is not standing any more, my mistake.